# Classification of tweets into 4 categories

Tags: python, twitter, lucene, classification, nltk

Ive referred to this similar query [twitter/facebook comments classification into various categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213496/twitter-facebook-comments-classification-into-various-categories) But my question is a bit different. I have some 10k tweets which I want to classify into 4 categories viz "travel", "shopping", "eating", "playing".
Now the thing is that since tweets are very small in length , what tools should one use to categorize these tweets into these 4 categories ? After removing stop-words and cleaning up the comments ,they get even smaller in size to hold any information relevant enough to classify them into 4 categories. What algorithm would work best in such a case : "small text" size that is.

I read somewhere that I should simply use Lucene instead of NLTK. But as Im new to Lucene I really dont understand how is Lucene going to be of any help in this multi-classification.

Comment: It really doesn't matter which platform you use python/java/R as long as you know what are you doing (the algorithms you use and etc.)

Comment: @badc0re thanks but what methodology would you suggest for classification of tweets. How shall I generate the features so as to classify them into the given categories. Pls if you could jot down some stepwise points Id be highly obliged. Thanks a ton pal !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try **[naive bayes](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_naive_bayes_1.html)**, **[random forest](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm)** or you can try with unsupervised algorithms like [**EM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) (and then define the labels based on the grouping of clusters). **Beware of common words that are used in all the classes.** You can try to evaluate your performance with AUC and etc. Also try to find methods for selecting features, known as **mutual information**

Good luck!

Comment: Hi I tried manual labelling of 100 documents for each of the label. Now I have 100 examples for each of the 4 categories. Which classifier shall I use now on this.

Comment: It is not that simple just to have training data, you should analyze also which features are used for each class and remove unnecessary noise. If you want to just see how the whole process works you can use Naive Bayes and see the prior probability of the class or the joint probability of the feature.

Comment: Thanks buddy, could you please suggest how to do this naive-bayes then I'd be ready to catch up. Or a tutorial which is on the lines of what you just wrote, coz there are way too many and I dont know which one to follow for my case.Trust me Ive been working on this problem since the day I posted it, hence I keep coming back only when Im stcuk with something. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Use the links of the answer, also these [data-mining](http://guidetodatamining.com/chapter-7/) and [Info-ret](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/).

Comment: will vowpal-wabbit help in this case ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what kind of framework or library you are using.