# NLP and Machine Learning in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, opennlp

I want to help my friend to analyze Posts on Social Networks (Facebook, Twitter, Linkdin and etc.) as well as several weblogs and websites.

When it comes to **Data Analyzing**, I need to analyze the feeling of people about a specific subject e.g. *The US Election*.
My idea is finding the sentences containing a set of the words/phrases (or tags) and looking for a set of adjectives or icons e.g :). I need a machine learning algorithm to reduce the mistakes (understand sarcastic posts, find new trends, and maybe more) and some toolkits to help me.

- Which model of [UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) works for me? or any other possible model.

I have also found [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) and [MontyLingua](http://web.media.mit.edu/~hugo/montylingua/) and [TweetNLP](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/). I tried to [check NLTK](http://text-processing.com/demo/) but it is not as good as I need. I need a toolkit which can process a sentence according to the whole meaning of that not words. I think [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904025/java-or-python-for-natural-language-processing) is great for this prat of my question but It will be great if anybody give a clue for the fastest with the least usage of resources.

Comment: You can find the complete answer on duplicated question, but as a brief answer, as far as i know and as i have experience with `NLTK`  you can use it to find the type of words (`Pos-tagger` or ... ) like adjectives or verbs, then you need a mathematical calculation maybe using probability to guess the emotions! and for math part you can use `Numpy` and `Scipy`

Comment: Also `Stanford NLP Parser` could be a good choice for such tasks!that `nltk` support it too! http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml