# Natural Language Processing Tools

Tags: nlp

Are there any good free NLP tools(for node)/APIs available for free? So far I found some github repos such as `natural`, that seem decent for basic senstence analysis, but not so good for more advanced stuff. Also I noticed the google NLP, but that isn't free. Anyone has experience working with these things and can recommend something free to use and powerful?

Comment: It's not really the good site to ask for this but you should look into microsoflt's NLTK or Spacy.io

Comment: @ted _**Microsoft's**_ NLTK?! What on earth...?

Comment: Try CogComp NLPy: https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlpy

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904025/java-or-python-for-natural-language-processing . Also see https://github.com/keon/awesome-nlp and https://github.com/alvations/awesome-community-curated-nlp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with the [Stafford NLP API](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/). I say this because of their good [NLP online courses](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/reports_2015.html)

Comment: Ok, this looks good. I found https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/other-languages.html which basically explains how to use the library in other languages. Thank you!